# android Call ListActivity from activity class

Tags: android-listview

I have layouts main activity and another list activity. But when i try to call list activity i am getting crash. Please help me to start list activity (Note: List activity has EditText and button to add text to existing listview in list Activity)
All i wanted to add text listview which is already exist in listactivity.
Many Thanks!!

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void onClick(View view){

    EditText txt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPass);
    if (txt.getText().length()==0){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter password to continue!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        txt.getText().clear();
        return;
    }

    if(txt.getText().toString().contains("Test")){
        Button btn;
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,Passwordlist.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you put your error log or your ListActivity code.

Answer (score 0):

First, make some change to your code:

```
    Button btn;
    EditText txt

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Do this stuff here and not in onClick. Your views should be defined in //onCreate() and before the onCLick() 
        txt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPass);
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
    }

    public void onClick(View view){

        Intent intent=new Intent(YourActivity.this,Passwordlist.class);

        if (txt.getText().toString().matches("")){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter password to continue!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            txt.getText().clear();
        }

        else if(txt.getText().toString().contains("Test")){

            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
```

See if this works.